# force:slds and lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

When extending an app using **force:slds**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <!--component reference>
</aura:application>
```

This should give me the logo instead of the alt text, is this a right assumption?

```
<aura:component>
    <div class="slds-global-header__logo">
        <img src="/assets/images/logo-noname.svg" alt="test" />
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[$Asset](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_asset.htm) is the merge variable to use images or SVG from the design systems .Try below code

```
<img src="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, 'assets/images/logo-noname.svg.jpg')}" alt="test" />
```

Update

For lightning components use the lightning:avatar

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_avatar.htm

```
<aura:component>
   <lightning:avatar src="/images/logo-noname.svg" alternativeText="Codey Bear"/>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: That's new, isn't it? A very nice addition to the platform.

Comment: Yes thats new addition

Comment: @MohithShrivastava  Sorry for unmarking this answer from solved. The URLFOR Is not supported in lightning components :(, I get an error  "No function found for key: URLFOR: Source" https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Lh2GAAS

Comment: Well i thought question was for VF page . If it is for lightning we can use avatar component i guess

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I was trying to replicate the global header using force:slds on my app without having to upload slds over static resource. I assumed I would get all the components like icons,images through force:slds tag. Looks like we still have to wait some more time(or) I totally misunderstood the usage of force:slds tag

Comment: It does come but you will need lightning specific tags .I updated ans as well .Did you try that

Comment: lightning:icon and Avatar should cover most of the cases

Comment: Lightning:Avatar worked :). Thanks again for the help Mohith